# What do I look for in replacing this shower knob? What is this style called?

Tags: shower, faucet, replacement, knobs

I have these shower knobs in an older shower stall. I want to replace the knobs only (the valves seem to be working fine).
I picked off the cover for the screw on one and found that there was a cross-shaped part underneath. However, I could not find any holes or crews that would let me take it off any further...

I'm looking for swap-in knobs that would mate properly with this cross-shaped base. Anyone know what this is called, or how I would find a set?

Thanks!

[image: Side view of knob base]

[image: Front view of knob base]

[image: Both knobs]

Comment: Look carefully on every part, including the ones you removed and the ones you didn't, for any markings or manufacturer names.  Maybe the back or inside of the plastic handle.  See if the part with the cross can just be yanked off.  See if there is a set screw inside the hole in the flange against the wall.

Comment: Good news, they look like regular valves (not one of those fancy mixing valves), one for hot one for cold. Once disassembled, you should be able to replace with any valve.

Comment: I think I found it. PRICE PFISTER 467213 MARQUIS DIVERTER HANDLE WITH 12 SPLINE BROACH. The cross-shaped part actually pulls off to reveal the stem and 12 spline broach. Thanks @jay613